# Julia fastest way to read values string to array

Tags: string, performance, optimization, type-conversion, julia

I have an array of multiple strings, whos values are actually arrays of various types, e.g.:

```
Julia> _string
"[(-33.8800966, 151.2069034), (-33.8801202, 151.2071933), (-33.8803442, 151.2083656), (-33.8804469, 151.2088682), (-33.8788247, 151.2104533)]"

Julia> typeof(_string)
String

Julia> _string2
"[1, 2, 3, 4]"

Julia> typeof(_string2)
String
```

I would like to convert to these into arrays quickly, I know the type of what each string is supposed to be beforehand.

i.e. so

```
Julia> convert(Array{Tuple(Float64, Float64)}, _string)
(-33.8800966, 151.2069034), (-33.8801202, 151.2071933), (-33.8803442, 151.2083656), (-33.8804469, 151.2088682), (-33.8788247, 151.2104533)]

Julia> convert(Array{Int,1}, _string2)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Currently i'm using `eval(Meta.parse(_string))` which is super slow when repeated millions of times.

What's a fast way to quickly read these strings into arrays?

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the best answer but one way to speed it up is to parse the strings exploiting any information on their structure you have, e.g. for your second example:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime parse.(Int64, split(replace(replace($_string2, "[" => ""), "]" => ""), ","))
  995.583 ns (19 allocations: 944 bytes)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Which compares to

```
julia> @btime eval(Meta.parse($_string2))
  135.553 μs (43 allocations: 2.67 KiB)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

on my machine.

How feasible this is will of course depend on whether you are able to find patterns in that way for all your strings quickly.

Comment: Note that you don't need two `replace` calls. Just provide as many replacement pairs as you like in a single call.

Comment: Apparently my previous comment is wrong: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/35327   According to the documentation, it _should_ work, though.

Comment: Yeah I think you need something like `foldl(replace, [...pairs...], init = _string)` to get it to work but I can never quite remember it and am usually too lazy to dig out the Discourse thread that has the solution :)

Comment: You can also use `chop(_string2; head=1, tail=1)` to remove the first and last character. This is much faster.

Comment: thanks guys this was helpful, i'll update your answer in a bit with what i used specifically to get the string read in faster